# What does it mean to include a string in an SQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, penetration-testing

I apologize if the question asked is simple and far too stretched out

I've been studying the fundamentals of SQL Injection attacks and at a point, I've read that a potential method of verifying the data type of a particular field in a UNION SQL Injection attack is by making certain changes to the request that we make to the target server.

The software being used is BurpSuite, and the target is a practice lab on the website https://portswigger.net. It is told that the category field is vulnerable, and that the query for the category returns two fields, so the following "code" is appended to the category part of the HTTPS GET message that we send to the server in an attempt to know the data type of the first field

```
...?category=Gift'+UNION+SELECT+'abc',NULL+FROM+table_that_contains_target_information--
```

According to the manuals for the lab, what we're doing with the `'abc',NULL` part is that we're verifying that the first field in the "table_that_contains_target_information", is of the type string/varchar. This seems to work and aids one in determining the data type of that particular field, as I checked in the lab, since if the first field's datatype is not a string/varchar, I would get an internal server error.

However, later on, when performing a query on a general database to check what the `'abc',NULL` part does in a general SELECT query, the results that come are somewhat different.
The general database question is one that is available to use for learning SQL at https://www.w3schools.com/mysql. It has a table named Customers with several fields. I know for a fact that the first field is an integer (via verification with information_schema.columns), and the rest are varchars. For context, in the Customers table, CustomerID is an integer field, and CustomerName is a varchar field. I ran the following query on the server

```
|-------This part is the original query-------||This is our inserted code to find out information about the database|
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName FROM Customers UNION SELECT 'abc',NULL FROM Customers
```

**Disclaimer: My intentions were not to cause any harm to the database, only to learn some SQL**

According to what I've learnt from the Lab manuals, I should be getting an error of sorts right?, since I'm checking the datatype of a field in a method that and unethical hacker could potentially take. However, all I get are the results of the original query and an extra record with values 'abc' and the second field is NULL.

I've tried to read up on documentation regarding the SELECT query in SQL, but as far as I was able to find, most of them tell about the general `SELECT * FROM table_name` or `SELECT column_name, other_column_name FROM table_name`. I wasn't able to find anything about the `SELECT 'abc' FROM table_name`.

Could anyone please explain what is going on here? Does the `SELECT 'abc' FROM table_name` just give me an extra record with 'abc'? If so, then why is this same query used to verify the datatypes in the lab at https://portswigger.net, and it seems to work its purpose there.

Thank you for answering in advance!

Comment: apparently the portswigger database is one that gives some sort of error when a union returns multiple types of data for the same column.  not all databases do so, in particular mysql does not.